# Scipy.Stats: Error associated to Laplace Fit parameters

Tags: python, regression

I have this model using scipy.stats to fit a Laplace distribution and obtain the parameters.

Here's the function I built:

```
def LaplaceFit(data, xmin, xmax, bins):
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, bins)
param = st.laplace.fit(data)
escala = (xmax-xmin)/bins*len(data)
fit = escala*st.laplace.pdf(x, loc=param[0], scale = param[1])
return escala, param[0], param[1]
```

The thing is: I study physics therefor I need to know what is the regression error associated to each parameter. Anyone knows how can I obtain it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Would you like to give some sample data and indent your code to have a working example? What is a regression error? Can you give me a link so I can try to understand it and give an answer?

Comment: For example:

numpy.random.laplace(25)

This generates 25 points of a (1,0) laplace distribution.

If I fit my function to this data, how can I get the associated regression errors to the obtained parameters?

Comment: Can you please update your code so that it compiles? Since this is a programming community, you should also give more information about the theory behind your question and explain how your results should look like. This will make it more likely to get a good answer. So far, it is rather difficult to answer without the mentioned knowledge that is still required.